# asp.net mvc RedirectToAction("Index") vs Index()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a controller with an Index Method and a Update Method. After the Update is done I want to redirect to Index(). Should I use return RedirectToAction("Index") or can I just call return Index()? Is there a difference?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View("Index", viewdata);
}

public ActionResult Update()
{
  // do updates
  return RedirectToAction("Index"); or
  return Index();
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the redirect otherwise the URL on the client will remain the same as the posted URL instead of the URL that corresponds to the Index action.

Answer (score 13):

Other things to consider:

- Redirect action after a POST will act more nicely when the user clicks Refresh button, since they won't be prompted to resend data to server.
- Form data will be lost with the redirect action unless you maintain them explicitly through, say, TempData.  Without doing this, your form controls won't have any value after a POST, which may be undesirable in some cases.

Comment: +1 for the resend data consideration, that one made the decision for me.

Comment: Another thing i noticed is that when i `return Index()` from another action, though i was expecting the system to get the `Index.cshtml` view, it was actually trying to get the original action's name view and because it was not existing i was getting an error.